# I want to join 3 tables from this data

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables.

**customers**

```
-------------------
custID | custName |
-------------------
   1   | 1        |
   2   | 2        |
   3   | 3        |
-------------------
```

**cars**

```
-------------------
carID  | custID   |
-------------------
  A    | 1        |
  B    | 1        |
  C    | 2        |
  D    | 2        |
  E    | 3        |
-------------------
```

**bill**

```
-------------------------------------
billNo | carID | custID | billTotal |
-------------------------------------
1      |   A   | 1      | 100       |
2      |   B   | 1      | 100       |
3      |   D   | 2      | 100       |
4      |   E   | 3      | 100       |
5      |   A   | 1      | 100       |
6      |   C   | 2      | 100       |
7      |   C   | 2      | 100       |
8      |   E   | 3      | 100       |
9      |   B   | 1      | 100       |
10     |   D   | 2      | 100       |
11     |   A   | 1      | 100       |
12     |   E   | 3      | 100       |
13     |   E   | 3      | 100       |
14     |   B   | 1      | 100       |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to make JOIN 3 tables as illustrated below.

```
----------------------------------------
custID | custName | countCar | sumBill |
----------------------------------------
1      | 1        |    2     |   600   |
2      | 2        |    2     |   400   |
3      | 3        |    1     |   400   |
---------------------------------------
```

what SQL code can make it show this result???
what SQL code can make it show this result???
what SQL code can make it show this result???
what SQL code can make it show this result???
what SQL code can make it show this result???

PS.my english is not well.

Comment: Please, add your example query

Comment: Why do you need the cars table for it seems to be contained in the bills table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  c.custID,
        c.custName,
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.carID) countCar,
        SUM(b.billTotal) sumBill
FROM    customers c INNER JOIN
        bill b  ON  c.custID = b.custID
GROUP BY    c.custID,
            c.custName
```

Have a look at [SQL COUNT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp), [SQL SUM() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp), [SQL GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

well I will not tell u the exact answer else u will not learn it but I will write whatever I understood from ur query

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*, TableC.*
FROM TableA
    JOIN TableB
        ON TableB.aID = TableA.aID
    JOIN TableC
        ON TableC.cID = TableB.cID
 GROUP BY    TableA.aID ,
                TableA.aName
```